# sed - preserve newline when writing to new file

Tags: sed, newlines

I have files containing data. This data sometimes has artifacts in them which I need to get rid of. An example line looks like this:

```
@@@@@@@@@@DK2018.4.24_0:0:0.200985,0.88,0.35,0.49,13.52,248.3
```

Or like this:

```
\2017.9.12_0:0:0.152507,0.02,0.82,0.10,11.76,181.8
\2017.9.12_0:0:0.554122,0.18,0.93,0.04,11.76,191.1
\2017.9.12_0:0:0.654682,0.06,0.89,0.10,11.74,184.0
\2017.9.12_0:0:0.755092,0.00,0.89,0.06,11.77,180.5
\2017.9.12_0:0:0.855754,0.02,0.87,0.09,11.76,181.4
\2017.9.12_0:0:0.955123,0.13,0.80,0.23,11.77,189.8
\2017.9.12_0:0:1.055499,0.10,0.82,0.35,11.76,187.6
\2017.9.12_0:0:1.155970,0.18,0.81,0.40,11.74,192.9
\2017.9.12_0:0:1.256581,0.15,0.91,0.44,11.74,189.3
\2017.9.12_0:0:1.356065,0.26,0.78,0.46,11.72,198.7
\2017.9.12_0:0:1.456712,0.37,0.69,0.33,11.74,208.1
```

In both cases some unwanted characters are in front of the date string. I need to remove those and keep everything else. Sometimes these artifacts are not in the date column, but in one of the other columns.

What I tried is using sed like this:

```
sed 's/[^0-9:_.,]*//g' dat.log > test.log
```

The aim was to delete everything but numbers, colons, underscores, dots and commas. And that works just fine. The problem is that sed doesn't write back the newline. I know that it takes it off during the process, but how can I get it back when the line is written to a file?

**edit:** Added more lines to the example input and added output from my sed command:

```
2017.9.12_0:0:0.051920,0.03,0.74,0.09,11.72,182.72017.9.12_0:0:0.152507,0.02,0.82,0.10,11.76,181.82017.9.12_0:0:0.253551,0.00,0.89,0.04,11.77,180.52017.9.12_0:0:0.353267,0.04,0.96,0.02,11.77,182.72017.9.12_0:0:0.453707,0.15,0.95,0.02,11.71,189.32017.9.12_0:0:0.554122,0.18,0.93,0.04,11.76,191.12017.9.12_0:0:0.654682,0.06,0.89,0.10,11.74,184.02017.9.12_0:0:0.755092,0.00,0.89,0.06,11.77,180.52017.9.12_0:0:0.855754,0.02,0.87,0.09,11.76,181.42017.9.12_0:0:0.955123,0.13,0.80,0.23,11.77,189.82017.9.12_0:0:1.055499,0.10,0.82,0.35,11.76,187.62017.9.12_0:0:1.155970,0.18,0.81,0.40,11.74,192.92017.9.12_0:0:1.256581,0.15,0.91,0.44,11.74,189.32017.9.12_0:0:1.356065,0.26,0.78,0.46,11.72,198.72017.9.12_0:0:1.456712,0.37,0.69,0.33,11.74,208.1
```

**edit2:** It turned out the problem was that the Raspberry Pi where the data is coming from, saved the files with the macintosh dataset. No idea why, but changing that using `tr '\r' '\n' < macfile.txt > unixfile.txt` first solved the problem.

Comment: sed would write back the newline, a Unix newline. If your original file is a DOS text file, then it would get converted to a Unix text file by your sed command since you would delete the carriage return at the end of each line. Do [edit] your question and add examples of what you're seeing.

Comment: You must give an actual example, because poor `sed` works line by line -- it reads line, and it writes lines, complete with terminating newline. It *cannot* not write a newline after every line it outputs.

Comment: added more input lines and the output from my command @AlexP. Files are coming from a Raspberry Pi and never saw DOS.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the behavior. On what operating system are you seeing this apparently impossible behavior?

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I can not reproduce what you are seeing.

Comment: Okay. When I copy my example code from here into a new file and use the sed command, it works. But then I don't get what the problem with the original source file is.

Comment: Post a hexdump of your file.

Comment: Solved the problem. See my second edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it seems like you can do:

```
tr -cd '0-9:_.,\r\n' < file.in > file.out
```

To remove all but those characters you want to keep including the line delimiters in whatever format they were initially.

Comment: That works great! And is a lot faster compared to sed!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you get rid of the `tr` and include that in the `sed` command:

```
sed 's/\(^\|^M\)[^0-9:_.,]*/\n/g; s/^\n//' file
```

May be a bit tricky to include the control characters  (^M, \r, 0x0D) and  (\n, 0x0A) in the `sed` script, depending on your OS and `sed` version.

Comment: Simply because I have no clue how that works. :) Your command doesn't do anything. The characters are still there and it is still in the macintosh char set.

Comment: You can enter control characters on the shell (`bash`) command line like `Ctrl-V Ctrl-M` for ^M and `Ctrl-V Ctrl-J` for `\n`.